# Using condition stored in a database table with Conditional Split in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a list of criteria in a database table that are entered by user. This criteria is in a format `X > 5` for Segment A, `X > 7` for segment B, and so on.

The data is collected using OLE DB Source where I specified a stored procedure to retrieve data. The record set has three columns: IdNumber, SegmentId and Total.

My conditional split should look like this:

SegmentId == 1 && Total > 5 (I would like to replace X with the actual value stored in Total column.
SegmentId == 1 && !(Total > 5)
... and so on.

So my question is, how can I use a condition which is string-based and stored in database in the Conditional Split Transformation Editor?

Regards,

Huske

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this from the editor; you will need to add code (e.g. in a Script Task) to query the database, get the condition, build a complete expression and then set it in the Conditional Split [programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136014.aspx#condsplit).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, however, I had to move quickly and have created two separate data flow tasks. One for the actual condition and one for NOT(actual condition) and pass this to a stored procedure that would execute sp_execsql. I have not tried Script Task inside Data Flow task yet, but I will give it a shot pretty soon and will let you know how it went. Thanks once more.